# how to make report generate faster ?( data pull out from a sql database)

Tags: sql, optimization, bigdata

my team uses SQL database for generating "daily active user" report
the size of the table we search is **about 7 million records**, and we tried our best
to optimize our algorithm, and put index on SQL db, **but still got 120 secs for**
each daily report generating.

is there any way to make it faster?

**any fields/keywords/books/forums that any one could recommend I could search for?**

---

detail information

**query definition:**

for an user who has logged in for consecutive 7 days we counted it as "active user"
at the end of 7 days

**table: login_in**

record basic info for login, logout time, account id

**programming language: java with seam framework**

**SQL db: MySQL**

---

many thx in advance!!

Comment: There are many ways to optimise queries - but you'll have to post some more details on how you are currently doing this; the tables involved and the SQL being used before anyone can answer

Comment: thx for ur helpful comments, I tried to add some details, hope it helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step would be to do an `EXPLAIN` on the query that is driving the report.  This can provide clues as to which part of the query are slow.  You want to make sure that all parts of the query are covered by an index rather than full table access.

See docs for [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html)